# else statement runs similar times as the database store in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I wants to check whether the input data stores in database or not. this code works but only when data is valid but if data is invalid else statement runs as many time as the number of columns present in my database.

```
<?php 
include_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$username= $_POST['user'];
$password= $_POST['pass'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM form1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if ( false===$result ) {
printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
else {
 //echo 'done.';
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$name = $row['username'];
$code = $row['password'];
if((($username == $name) && ($username!="" )) && (($password == $code) && 
($password!="")) )
{
echo "valid";
header("Location:practice.php");
}
else{
echo "please enter correct username <br/>";
}
}
}
?>
```

**output**:

```
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username 
please enter correct username

}
```

`#18` database values store in my database and its displays this message 18 times
i didn't understand what is the issue with this code

Comment: Remove the `else` statement, and put your echo after the while loop.

Comment: check your `if else` statement.

Comment: But, I really think that's not the right way to check values from database. Search about `WHERE` clause in your query and use [paramaterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: change your `query` use `WHERE` clause

Comment: Also read [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/password_verify) and [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: If you'd indented your code properly, you'd be able to see the problem.